# calling knockout model function on ajax success outside of scope

Tags: javascript, function, jquery, knockout.js

I have a model like this

```
function DetailsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Day = ko.observable();
    self.DateNumber = ko.observable();
    self.Details = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.LoadData = function () {

        var data = { date: '2013-09-18' }
        var url = "php/abc.php"
        var callback = self.Result();

        ajax(url , data , self.Result , type );

        /*
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Timesheet/DayDetailResult",
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            data: ko.toJSON(data),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (details) {
                self.DateNumber(details.DateNumber);
                self.Day(details.Day);
                self.Details(details.Details);
            }
        });
        */
    };

    self.AddDayDetails = function () {
        window.location.href = '/Home/AddTimeSheetEntry';
    }

    self.Result = function (details) {
        self.DateNumber(details.DateNumber);
        self.Day(details.Day);
        self.Details(details.Details);            
    }

    self.LoadData();
}
```

And here is ajax function

```
function ajax(url , data , callback , type ) {

    var type = (type === undefined) ? "GET" : type;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false,
        type: type,
        data: ko.toJSON(data),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: callback(data)
    });
}
```

The problem is that when i uncomment ajax request inside self.LoadData function everything works fine. But i want to use a global ajax function throughout my application. I am defining self.Result which need to get data from ajax success and should be called from ajax success. How can i do that. When i run my code i get this error

```
`details is undefined`
```

I assume here should be done something to get it working but i dont know how.

```
ajax(url , data , self.Result , type );
```

Please help. I am no Javascript expert.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? When running your code I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateNumber' of undefined `...

Comment: it says `details is undefined` not moving ahead so how come you are getting this error

Comment: Your `var callback = self.Result();` throwing this error because your are calling `Result` without any arguments. Remove this line: `var callback = self.Result();` and see what is happening.

Comment: thanks for thati have removed that but i am still unable to call self.Result inside ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short here is the correct answer to this problem

```
function DetailsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Day            =   ko.observable();
    self.DateNumber     =   ko.observable();
    self.Details        =   ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedJob    =   ko.observable();

    self.LoadData = function () {

        var data = { date: '2013-09-18' }
        var url = "php/abc.php"
        var callback = self.Result();

        ajax(url , data , self.Result , type );
    };

    self.Result = function (callbackData) {
        self.DateNumber(callbackData.DateNumber);
        self.Day(callbackData.Day);
        self.Details(callbackData.Details);            
    }

    self.LoadData();
}
```

As you can see here i am calling self.Result in my custom ajax function.
It is required to have a parameter(s) in self.Result function as here is
callbackData.

And in the custom function simple put callback in success.

```
function ajax(url , data , callback , type ) {

    var type = (type === undefined) ? "GET" : type;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false,
        type: type,
        data: ko.toJSON(data),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: callback
    });
}
```

You can use any function instead of self.Result.
Take a look at this example

```
self.getJobs = function () {
    var data = null
    var url = "/api/Timesheet/JobResult"
    var type = 'GET';

    ajax(url, data, self.JobResults, type);
}

self.JobResults = function (jobdata) {
    self.Jobs(jobdata.Details);
}

self.getTasks = function () {
    var data = { JobId: self.SelectedJob() }
    var url = "/api/Timesheet/TaskResult"
    var type = 'GET';

    ajax(url, data, self.TaskResults, type);
}

self.TaskResults = function (taskdata) {
    self.Tasks(taskdata.Details);
}
```

Note i have defined self.JobResults for getJobs success
And self.getTasks for getTasks success

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

- You have an extra line `var callback = self.Result();` which executes your `Result` function without any arguments which throw the exception: `details is undefined` so remove this erroneous line.
- Your main problem is with your `success: callback(data)` line because this immediately executes your callback with the provided `data` value and assign its return value to the `success` property which is `undefined`.

  What you want here is directly pass your `callback` reference:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      async: false,
      type: type,
      data: ko.toJSON(data),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: callback
  });
  ```

Comment: but it is still not working. Although i have found an alternate way like this. Sending this. `ajax(url , data , this , type );` and in ajax request `success : object.Result` where `function ajax(url , data , object , type)`. Its working now.

Comment: thanks for giving suggestion in success for calling function directly without parameter. `success: callback`

Comment: the order does not matter here. By the way this is better. `ajax(url , data , self.Result , type );` and in ajax function `success : callback`. Thanks again